# Django tried these URL patterns: The empty path didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am getting this error

> Request Method:   GET Using the URLconf defined in Webwork.urls, Django
> tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> admin/ 
> ^ ^department/$ 
> ^ ^department/([0-9]+)$ 
> ^ ^employee/$
> ^ ^employee/([0-9]+)$
> ```
>
> The empty path didn’t match any of these.

here is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include    
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',include('EmpApp.urls'))
]
```

and

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from EmpApp import views
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^department/$',views.departmentApi),
    url(r'^department/([0-9]+)$',views.departmentApi),
    url(r'^employee/$',views.employeeApi),
    url(r'^employee/([0-9]+)$',views.employeeApi),
    
]
```

Can anyone please help me solve this error?

Comment: You don't have pattern for the **root** page with "empty path".

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Do you have a view for the home/root page of your website?

Comment: Yes I have it on the website

Comment: Put it to urlpatterns how you did for other views.

Answer (score 1):

*you didn't have any error it's you didn't have created any page for http://127.0.0.1:8000 this path*

use ***path*** instead of ***url*** as i shown in my code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import  include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index), # added this line 
    path('departments',views.departmentApi),
    path('departments/<slug:id>',views.departmentApi)
]
```

and add code to  ***EmpAppapp\views.py*** file

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, './index.html')
```

now create ***index.html*** File in ***EmpAppapp\templates\index.html*** and write anything you want to display on the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ page

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

if you get ***ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'*** this error than refer this page
[ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' after upgrading to Django 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319606/importerror-cannot-import-name-url-from-django-conf-urls-after-upgrading-to)