# ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-url-reverse

ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (/home/chams/pfe_project/CarApp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/urls/_*init*_.py)

I can't find any mistakes in my code !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' after upgrading to Django 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319606/importerror-cannot-import-name-url-from-django-conf-urls-after-upgrading-to)

Answer (score 2):

django.conf.urls.url() was deprecated in Django 3.0, and is removed in Django 4.0+.
The easiest fix is to replace url() with re_path()

You will be using this,

from django.conf.urls import url

Instead use this:

from django.urls import re_path as url

Comment: While this is an answer, it's a "copy" of the previous answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/71628531/6143954. There is no additional value for SO to keep multiple answers with the same solution.

Comment: I have the same error I can't understand what you say. this error happened in the library not in my code the path error occurs is: venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compat/__init__.py

Answer (score 1):

`django.conf.urls.url` was deprecated and removed in Django 4.0.

Use `django.urls.re_path` instead.

Answer (score 1):

for Django 4.0.

> from django.urls import re_path as url